# Neo4j How to drop a duplicated EDGE?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am learning Cypher / Neo4j, using C# 
I created this the EDGE 3 times.

```
  client.Cypher
               .Match("(user1:Person)", "(user2:Person)")
               .Where((Person user1) => user1.name == "Tony")
               .AndWhere((Person user2) => user2.name == "Maria Esther")
               //.Create("(user1)-[:PAI]->(user2)")
               .Create("(user2)-[:FILHO {DataDeNascimento: '2006'}]->(user1)")
               .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

How to drop the 2 other **:FILHO** (duplicated edges)?

[image: My Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will delete duplicate `:FILHO` relationships between `Person` nodes:

```
MATCH (p1:Person)-[r:FILHO]->(p2:Person)
WITH p1, p2, COLLECT(r) as rels
FOREACH(r IN tail(rels) | DELETE r)
```

First, it matches on all `FILHO` relationships and `Person` nodes. 
Then aggregates the relationships for each pair of `Person` nodes into the `rels` collection.
Then iterates through the tail of each `rels` collection (all relationships, but the first) and deletes them.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to consider how to avoid creating dupicate edges. Consider using merge rather than create.